# Spring boot getting (and editing) an entity with multiple path variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, entity, path-variables

I am in a very similar situation to the question here: [Spring boot how to edit entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904389/spring-boot-how-to-edit-entity).

I have an "Item" entity for which I want to edit a number of attributes (possibly one, possibly all of them) - but the key. I have understood that `BeanUtils.copyProperties(sourceItem, targetItem, "id");` is great for such cases. From the question that I linked, I have also further seen that a way of doing this edit is simply through creating an update method in the controller as follows:

```java
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable("id") Item targetItem, @RequestBody Item sourceItem) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(sourceItem, targetItem, "id");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(repo.save(targetItem));
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that I have more than one path variable. Thus to edit the item, i would rather need something like `@PutMapping("/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}")`, since the item itself is linked to other items.

Thus what I tried doing (based on the linked question) is:

```java
@PutMapping("/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable("id1/id2/id3") Item targetItem, @RequestBody Item sourceItem) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(sourceItem, targetItem, "id3");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(repo.save(targetItem));
}
```

I think the faulty part is `@PathVariable("id1/id2/id3")`, since the IDE does tell me that the pathing cannot be found.

I would like to know if you can think of an elegant way of dealing with the multiple variables issue - I feel like using `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` is a clean way of editing something and I would enjoy keeping that intact.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should map to 3 different path variables:

```
@PutMapping("/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable("id1") Item targetItem1
@PathVariable("id2") Item targetItem2, @PathVariable("id3") Item targetItem3, @RequestBody Item sourceItem) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(sourceItem, targetItem1, "id");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(repo.save(targetItem1));
}
```